# Android: Service implements MediaPlayer.onPreparedListener

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I have a web radio stream which i want to implement using MediaPlayer as a service
the Main Activity has 2 buttons, play & stop which set the service as the intent then start or stop the service depending on the button

RadioPlayer service

```
public class RadioPlayer extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{

public static String ACTION_PLAY = "ACTION_PLAY";
private MediaPlayer mediaplayer = null;
private boolean isPlaying = false;


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Log.d("SERVICE", "Started");
    if(intent.getBooleanExtra(ACTION_PLAY, false)){
            play(); 
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private void play(){
    Log.d("SERVICE", "play()");
    if(!isPlaying){

        isPlaying = true;

        try{
          Log.d("SERVICE", "1");    
          mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
          Log.d("SERVICE", "2");
          mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
          Log.d("SERVICE", "3");
          mediaplayer.setDataSource("http://X.X.X.X");
          Log.d("SERVICE", "4");
          mediaplayer.prepareAsync();
          Log.d("SERVICE", "5");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



public void onDestory(){
    Log.d("SERVICE", "Stop");
    stop();
}

private void stop(){
    Log.d("SERVICE", "stop()");
    if(isPlaying){
        isPlaying = false;
        if(mediaplayer != null){
            mediaplayer.stop();
            mediaplayer.release();
            mediaplayer = null;
        }
        //stopForeground(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d("SERVICE", "onPrepared()");
    mediaplayer.start();
            //i have also attempted mp.start() with no cigar

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) does not get called (& i have waited a good amount of time for the stream to load up). 
Have i missed something that i would need for a service to successfully implement onPreparedListener?

In terms of Log cat output, the only thing that occurs when executed that i don't recognize is AwesomePlayer saying the data source is supressed...?

```
06-19 16:45:04.090: D/pre-SERVICE(22731): clicked()
06-19 16:45:04.090: D/SERVICE(22731): Started
06-19 16:45:04.090: D/SERVICE(22731): play()
06-19 16:45:04.090: D/SERVICE(22731): 1
06-19 16:45:04.110: W/qdhwcomposer(327): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 66 ms
06-19 16:45:04.110: D/SERVICE(22731): 2
06-19 16:45:04.110: D/SERVICE(22731): 3
06-19 16:45:04.110: I/AwesomePlayer(331): setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
06-19 16:45:04.110: D/SERVICE(22731): 4
06-19 16:45:04.110: D/SERVICE(22731): 5
06-19 16:45:04.190: W/qdhwcomposer(327): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 49 ms
```

UPDATE
After trying it with just .onPrepare i have managed to get the service to work, however if i were to do this async style, the question still stands

Answer (score 1):

It's seems you don't set your onCompletionListener with your player.

Try to add `mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(this)` after `mediaplayer.prepareAsync()`.

Comment: i'm not sure onCompletionListener would work with an internet stream as, well, the stream never completes. i've tried it with just .onPrepare & it works! however the question does still stand about with it asynchronously

Comment: I've tried it with a stream and it work. The documentation on `prepareAsync` say "For streams, you should call prepareAsync(), which returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been buffered."

Answer (score 0):

It seem's this issue is subjective.
i did manage to get sucsessful stream asynchronously using this code

```
mediaplayer.prepareAsync();
mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)}
    mp.start();
} });
```